# Can't obtain InputStream for win32-x86-64/xpde.dll

Tags: java, dll

I am getting this error :

failed with throwable.Unable to load library 'xpde': Can't obtain InputStream for win32-x86-64/xpde.dll

When trying to load the dll using jna-4.5.1-direct.jar

My code is :

```
NativeLibrary JNA_NATIVE_LIB = NativeLibrary.getInstance("xpde",
                Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

I am using :

```
JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_232"
OS_NAME="Windows"
OS_VERSION="5.2"
OS_ARCH="amd64"
```

[image]

I am not sure if xpde.dll is 32 bit or 64 bit .
The dll is in a dll folder in my classpath
Is this the problem ? or other problem ?

Comment: I think you are using this https://github.com/java-native-access/jna, right? Would you try to set the jna.library.path system property to the path to your xpde.dll,

Answer (score 0):

yes I was missing

```
 jna.library.path
```